# Current application losing focus randomly

Tags: macos, mojave

Lately the active window of the current application (no matter what is it) started losing focus randomly about once a minute.

This usually happens when another process/application takes focus.

Apparently the active application stays the same: the menubar does not change.

Is there any way to investigate what process has focus, perhaps with a terminal script running in the background?

Answer (score 1):

I found in my case the guilty was GlobalProtect from Palo Alto Networks (essentially a vpn client) when trying to connect to the remote network and the remote network cannot be reached.

Disabling it when the remote network isn't available solved the problem.